# Update Manager broken package libxext6 and libxext6:i386

Tags: apt, updates, package-management, dpkg

This problem seems similar to some, but none of the fixes work. When I try to update, it reads/displays the packages, but it will not install. The error message I got in the terminal is:

```
dpkg: error processing libxext6 (--configure):
 libxext6:amd64 2:1.3.0-3build1 cannot be configured because libxext6 is in a different version (2:1.3.0-3ubuntu0.1)
dpkg: error processing libxext6:i386 (--configure):
 libxext6:i38 2:1.3.0-3ubuntu0.1 cannot be configured because libxext6:amd64 is in a different version (2:1.3.0-3build1)
Errors were encountered while processing:
libxext6
libxext6:i386
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned and error code
```

I have an Intel processor, not an AMD, if that helps.

What should I do? I've tried:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get clear
sudo apt-get autoclear
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and a few other commands.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
```

As far as your architecture goes, Ubuntu calls 64bit packages AMD64, regardless of your processor being AMD or Intel.

Report if this works.